# Passing an array from the view to a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to pass an array from a view to a controller. So far I have this:

```
<form method="post">
    <% for(let i = 0; i < websites.length; i++){ let website = websites[i]; %>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="website<%= i %>" class="col-sm-2">Website <%= i + 1 %></label>
        <input name="website<%= i %>" id="website<%= i %>" value="<%= website %>" type="text"/>
    </fieldset>
    <% } %>
    <button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-2">Generate report</button>
</form>
```

And this is the controller

```
const websites = Object.keys(req.body).filter(key => key.startsWith('website'));
console.log(websites);
```

The problem is the console logs this:

```
[ 'website0', 'website1' ]
```

So I'm guessing it's grabbing the names. How do I make grab the values instead?

Comment: yeah, you're grabbing the keys here. You could loop onto the result of the filters and add an item in the array using the value of the Object at that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is using the function `map`

```
const websites = Object.keys(req.body)
                       .filter(key => key.startsWith('website'))
                       .map(k => req.body[k]);
```